# Access to the terminal while you are on Vim

Tags: vim, process, background-process

Is there a way to access the terminal while using [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29)?

I do not like to open another terminal or save and exit the current terminal.

Comment: Open a new tab? (Ctrl + Shift + T)

Comment: How many times do that :) I do not like to do that D:

Comment: Have you tried using a terminal window manager like tmux?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can send vim the SIGTSTP signal. You do this by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. Vim will get suspended in the background, and you can use the terminal. Type `fg` in the terminal to resume with vim.

Bonus tip: This works on nearly all terminal applications. Use `bg` to enable the application to continue running in the background.

Comment: Or just `%` instead of `fg`. Or `%1`, `%2`, etc. if you have many background jobs. `jobs` command will list them. (Assuming `bash` as the shell.)

Comment: I vote for the ^z (and later fg) method, because this can be used in almost all shell processes - it's not a vim thing, it's a how-to-use-shell trick that is incredibly useful in other contexts.

Answer (score 36):

In vim, just type:

```
:!sh
```

`:!` launches an external process -- in this case `sh`, another shell. Control will return to vim once you exit the shell. If you want to use the shell concurrently with vim, add `&` to the end of the sh command:

```
:!sh&
```

Comment: Or just use `:shell`.

Comment: This is the best answer for most purposes.

Comment: That's nice but what about when the command is running a server, like `http-server` and it prints out logs that I want to view? I'd like to be able to switch over to my files, make edits, then switch back to the logs.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `:shell` command (or the short form `:sh`). From `:help :shell`:

> This command starts a shell.  When the shell exits (after the "exit" command) you return to Vim.  The name for the shell command comes from 'shell' option.

By default, on Ubuntu, this will give you bash. type `exit` to return to vim when you're done.

Answer (score 13):

Since recent vim you can now do:

```
:terminal
```

This was initially added in Vim [8.0.693](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/e4f25e4a8db2c8a8a71a4ba2a68540b3ab341e42), but with lots of bugs. See [`:help terminal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/terminal.txt.html#terminal):

```
WARNING: THIS IS ONLY PARTLY IMPLEMENTED, ANYTHING CAN STILL CHANGE

The terminal feature is optional, use this to check if your Vim has it: 
        echo has('terminal')
If the result is "1" you have it.   

[...]

The terminal feature requires the +multi_byte, +job and +channel features.

==============================================================================
1. Basic use                                            terminal-use

This feature is for running a terminal emulator in a Vim window.  A job can be
started connected to the terminal emulator. For example, to run a shell: 
     :term bash

Or to run a debugger: 
     :term gdb vim

The job runs asynchronously from Vim, the window will be updated to show
output from the job, also  while editing in any other window.
```

Answer (score 7):

As addition to all answers.

You can install [ConqueTerm plugin](https://code.google.com/p/conque/)

This plugin provide ability to run interactive programs inside vim buffers.

After installation you can add this 2 lines to your **`.vimrc`**:

```
:nnoremap <S-w> :q!<CR>
:nnoremap <S-t> :ConqueTermSplit bash<CR>
```

And you will be able to run `bash` by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and close current Conque tab by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

It is perferct if you need fast open/close `bash`.

Here is [gif](http://gifmaker.me/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2014071322cnc0LreEKEQrsKyJ5IWBnO&file=output_hhANF3.gif) that showing how it is look like

Comment: can you please consider updating the posts? The links you mentioned seems outdated

Answer (score 4):

Another option with either screen or byobu is to open a tab within those programs. These programs make it fairly easy to keep a terminal-session  c.q. shell open and switch between those screens with the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

With new version of vim 8.1 all you need to do is just `:terminal` and voila! 
(this is built in)